# FragmentTransaction add method is accepting the wrong parameter

Tags: java, android

Hey guys I was learning how to create an Android apps and today I am trying to make  Fragment. So the method add has several type of parameter input (cause Android studio shows me 3 different parameter input), like (Fragment, String) (Int, Fragment) and (Int, Fragment, String). What I want to do is to use the first type of parameter, but somehow AndroidStudio keeps on detecting my code as (Int, Fragment).

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qUe6.jpg)

I have looked up in the other stackoverflow forum and I have make sure that I use

*import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;*

Here is my code btw:

```
package listview.bookapp.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import listview.bookapp.R;

public class ProfileMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

Button profileMain;
Button profileEdit;
FrameLayout frameLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_main);

    profileMain = findViewById(R.id.profile_main);
    profileEdit = findViewById(R.id.profile_edit);
    frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameForFragment);

    profileMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ProfileMainFragment profileMainFrag = new ProfileMainFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.frameForFragment, profileMainFrag);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

    profileEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ProfileEditFragment profileEditFrag = new ProfileEditFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.frameForFragment, profileEditFrag);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Wonder if I missed something or this is just a bug from AndroidStudio (I am using Android Studio 3.2.1).

Cheers!

Comment: Does ProfileMainFragment extend from Fragment? Did you import the correct version of Fragment (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`)?

Comment: @BenP. DUDEEEE THANK YOU SOO MUCH!! IT WORKS NOW